# why I tried to use cgo to link dylib file on mac fail?

Tags: go, cgo

```
    package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I./lib
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L./lib -lfifo
// #include "shmfifo.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    fifo := C.shmfifo_init(13, 3, 64)
    for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
        C.shmfifo_put(fifo, 9)
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh79a.png)

that is my project structure, error msg blow:

```
$ go build pppp.go 
# command-line-arguments
ld: library not found for -lfifo
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I compile shmfifo into ./lib dir, so go project has a lib dir, and has shmfifo.dylib file, I also point out #cgo CFLAGS and #cgo LDFLAGS, why "ld: library not found"

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue seems to be isolated to your linker is not finding the `libfifo.dylib` file. So hence the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lfifo
```

I would recommend either:

1. Replacing the relative reference in the `-L` args with the special cgo variable `$SRCDIR` to more explicitly point to the location. [More on that in the godocs.](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#:%7E:text=When%20the%20cgo%20directives%20are%20parsed%2C%20any%20occurrence%20of%20the%20string%20%24%7BSRCDIR%7D%20will%20be%20replaced%20by%20the%20absolute%20path%20to%20the%20directory)
2. You can also copy the directory structure and cgo args in the following [cgo/dylib tutorial](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/08/using-c-dynamic-libraries-in-go-programs.html) by copying the libfifo file (assuming it can also link to other dependencies without issue).

Comment: my code now is `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/lib -lfifo`, on go doc said: `// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/libs -lfoo` equals `// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/go/src/foo/libs -lfoo`,my code is not the same as that? this is a file named 'fifo.dylib' in $SRCDIR/lib/,`$SRCDIR/lib/fifo.dylib`,but command line also said `not found`

Comment: keyboard example said the lib file must start with "lib",so my lib file should be "libfifo.dylib"?

Comment: `go build pppp.go
# command-line-arguments
ld: warning: dylib (/Volumes/DATA/ts/lib/libfifo.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (13.0) than being linked (12.0)
# command-line-arguments
./pppp.go:11:112: cannot use _cgo1 (variable of type int) as type unsafe.Pointer in argument to _Cfunc_shmfifo_put` , seem code is correct

Comment: that last error shows good linking. Then you have two errors after that 1) saying that the libfifo is built for a newer version of MacOS (may just be a warning) 2) you need to cast the argument to `shmfifo_put` to `C.Int` instead of just a Go `Int`